# Cypress e2e testing: How to get all the elements from dynamic dropdown and should verify using test data(more than 200 items)

Tags: javascript, cypress, dropdown

[image: HTML code of the dropdown items]

I wrote the code like this but I could get until 13 items only, after that it's not going for next elements. I could see the next elements when I scroll down in dropdown and it goes on... I am not sure how this works, but I think its due to the behavior of bindings in HTML.

Please can someone help to get all the elements or any other way to test this in Cypress?

```
cy.visit('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/account/signup')
        cy.get('span.ng-tns-c381-0').contains('Account Name').click()
        cy.wait(15000)
        cy.get('p-dropdownitem > li > div').each(($ele, i)=>{
            cy.wrap($ele).invoke('text').then((text)=>{
                cy.log(text)
                expect(text).to.equal(accoun_Data.dropdowntext1[i])
                })
             })
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a virtual scroll, so you can't get all the elements on first query. Looks like 13 at a time are loaded.

If you have an input associated, you might be able to `.type()` some text to filter the list.

You would only need to check the first and last items.

Otherwise, the virtual list needs to be scrolled to load the remainder.

---

#### A working example from the docs

An example of first-and-last testing of a virtual scroll box, using the basic example from the docs (100,000 items).

Note, Cypress does not wait for the `.scrollTo('bottom')` to complete it's action, so you have to bump the timeout up substantially when testing the bottom of the list.

```js
cy.get('cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport')
  .find('.example-item').eq(0)
  .should('have.text', 'Item #0')

cy.get('cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport')
  .scrollTo('bottom')
  .find('.example-item', {timeout: 10000}) 
  .should('contain', 'Item #99999')
```

Your test would be similar, but you need to change the final index from `999` to whatever it is for your data.

```js
cy.get('cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport')
  .find('p-dropdownitem > li > div').eq(0)
  .should('have.text', accoun_Data.dropdowntext1[0])

cy.get('cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport')
  .scrollTo('bottom')
  .find('p-dropdownitem > li > div', {timeout: 10000})
  .should('contain', accoun_Data.dropdowntext1[999])    // change index
```

Also note, the 2nd `should()` uses `contain` not `have.text` because you are checking the text from the last 13 items.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the code by using `$ele.text()`. And you can also add `trim()` to remove trailing spaces.

```js
cy.get('p-dropdownitem > li > div').each(($ele, i) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim()).to.equal(accoun_Data.dropdowntext1[i])
})
```